# vim update complete popup as I type

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I am trying to use `complete()` in `vim` so that it reads the value as well.

For example, from `vim`'s `complete()` example,

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=ListMonths()<CR>

func! ListMonths()
  call complete(col('.'), ['January', 'February', 'March',
    \ 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
    \ 'October', 'November', 'December'])
  return ''
endfunc
```

if I type `<F5>` I will get all the months as a pop up. Now, what I want is, if I type "J", only January, June and July will be shown, "Ju" will give June and July, and so on.

I read the `vim-doc`, and tried `complete_check`, but that's not.

Also, I have tried to use [omnicomplete](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-omni) example `E839`  in `vimdoc`, but I cant properly call it, always getting invalid argument.

Please suggest me the the preferred method of menu with completion as I type, and how to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that example completion does not take an already typed base into account, because it always starts completion at the cursor position (via `col('.')`).

Second, to get the "refine list as you type" behavior, you need the following setting:

```
:set completeopt+=longest
```

Unfortunately, due to a [(long known) bug](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/crY29kvAbBQ/ReHL1AUADKUJ), `complete()` doesn't consider the `'completeopt'` option. You have to use `'completefunc'` instead, like in this rewritten example:

```
fun! CompleteMonths(findstart, base)
    if a:findstart
        " locate the start of the word
        let line = getline('.')
        let start = col('.') - 1
        while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
            let start -= 1
        endwhile
        return start
    else
        echomsg '**** completing' a:base
        " find months matching with "a:base"
        let res = []
        for m in ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
            if m =~ '^' . a:base
            call add(res, m)
            endif
        endfor
        return res
    endif
endfun
inoremap <F5> <C-o>:set completefunc=CompleteMonths<CR><C-x><C-u>
```