# pass vim argument in completefunc

Tags: vim

I am writing a `vimscript` that uses `completefunc` as:

```
" GetComp: Menu and Sunroutine Completion {{{1
function! GetComp(arg, findstart, base)
if a:findstart
    " locate the start of the word
    let line = getline('.')
    let start = col('.') - 1
    while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
        let start -= 1
    endwhile
    return start
else
    echomsg '**** completing' a:base
python << EOF
import vim
import os
flsts = [' ']

path = "."
for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for tfile in files:
        if tfile.endswith(('f90', 'F90', 'f', 'F')):
            ofile = open(dirs+'/'+tfile)
            for line in ofile:
                if line.lower().strip().startswith(vim.eval("a:arg")):
                    modname = line.split()[1]
                    flsts.append(modname)
vim.command("let flstsI = %s"%flsts)                    
EOF
if eval("a:arg") = "module"
  for m in ["ieee_arithmatic", "ieee_exceptions", "ieee_features", "iso_c_bindings", "iso_fortran_env",  "omp_lib", "omp_lib_kinds"]
    if m =~ "^" . a:base
      call add(flstsI, m)
    endif
  endfor
elseif eval("a:arg") = "subroutine"
for m in ["alarm()", "date_and_time()", "backtrace", "c_f_procpointer()", "chdir()", "chmod()", "co_broadcast()", "get_command()", "get_command_argument()", "get_environment_variable()", "mvbits()", "random_number()", "random_seed()"]
  if m =~ "^" . a:base
    call add(flstsI, m)
  endif
endfor
endif

return flstsI
endif
endfunction
```

I will call it for 2 different argument as:

```
inoremap <leader>call  call <C-o>:set completefunc=GetComp("subroutine", findstart, base)<CR><C-x><C-u>
inoremap <leader>use  use <C-o>:set completefunc=GetComp("module", findstart, base)<CR><C-x><C-u>
```

But trying so, gives error: `Unknown function GetComp(`

I don't know how to call them. 
If I don't use `arg`, then,   using this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745939/vim-update-complete-popup-as-i-type/34747283#34747283), I can call this perfectly.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to attach a context to your completion. If you look closely at [my message on vi.se](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/dynamic-completion), you'll see a framework that permits to bind data to a user-completion. From there in your mapping, it just becomes a question of which context to attach.

A simplified way would be to execute a (preparation) function from the mappings and have the function set script global variables that will be used in your completion function.

Comment: oh thanks! I was not aware of different site for `vi`.